# How to read geo location from an image file data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, browser, geolocation, exif

How to read geolocation data from an image file (JPG, JPEG, PNG, etc) in Javascript at the moment of loading the file onto web browser but before the actual upload (on the client side).

Comment: You can use this one: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called `exif` you could use like this:

```
var ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;

try {
    new ExifImage({ image : 'myImage.jpg' }, function (error, exifData) {
        if (error)
            console.log('Error: '+error.message);
        else
            console.log(exifData); // Do something with your data!
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
}
```

You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to convert this npm module for use in the browser.